# How to query for dynamic amount of aliases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Assume I have a GraphQL Schema like this:

```
Schema {
  user($id: ID) {
    id: ID
    name: String
  }
}
```

I know how to query for one user by his ID, and I could use aliases to query for several users like so:

```
GetSomeMore {
  john: user(id: "123") {
    name
  }
  mary: user(id: "321") {
    name
  }
}
```

However, assume I just have a list of user IDs, and would like to query for the names of each one of them. How would I write a query like that?

The approaches I can come up with is ether dynamically generating a query with aliases like `user1`, `user2`, etc., or implementing a `users(ids: [ID])` edge on the server. But I feel like there should be a better solution. Is there?

*(PS: my code examples might have syntax errors, I'm writing it more as pseudocode, to get my point across.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement that functionality as part of your schema, for example with a `id_in: [String]` argument to the `users` query.

At Graphcool, we use the `filter` argument to expose functionality like this. For example, your query could be done like this:

```
query {
  allUsers(filter: {id_in: ["123", "321"]}) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

results in

```
{
  "data": {
    "allUsers": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "John"
      },
      {
        "id": "321",
        "name": "Mary"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To read more about the `filter` argument check [the documentation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/filtering-by-field).

Comment: Ok, this seems pretty usable, and I see that it's a superset of the previous "one user" edge. However, it seems practical to have an edge for getting just one user (man use cases look just like that). Do you think one should remove the "one user" edge and just go with your solution, or keep both?

Comment: yes, it makes a lot of sense! we also have the `User` query to return one `User`. It accepts the `id` argument, or any field on the `User` model that you declared as `unique` in our console UI. for example, if you have unique names for users you can query like this: `query { User(name: "John") { id } }`

Comment: Hi @marktani! Does your implementation of `filter` in open source? :)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with your last proposition:

```
Schema {
  users($ids: [ID]) {
    id: ID
    name: String
  }
}
```

With a resolver like:

```
const users = async (root, { ids }) => await knex('users').whereIn('id', ids)
```

Note: I use [graphql-js](/questions/tagged/graphql-js) + [graphql-tools](/questions/tagged/graphql-tools) + [knex.js](/questions/tagged/knex.js) to create my schema, my types and my resolvers.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no built-in capability to do that in GraphQL?

Comment: I don't think so. There is nothing magic about GraqhQL: when you start doing complex queries, you have to write a lot of codes to generate the result. :)

Comment: I also prefer this approach. It tells which users to fetch in a lean and simple way. Use of `filter`, `*_in`, `AND`, `OR` forces client-side to think in terms of DB - not a good GraphQL API design, IMHO.

Comment: it doesn't force clients to think in DB at all. combining these filters and handle the logic server side goes pretty much in the GraphQL spirit imo. the alternative would be to fetch all users and filter them client side...